# Printing object variable of Java inbuilt class vs Printing object of my class

Tags: integer, object-reference, java

In my Java project, I have a class called `myInteger` with the following code:

```
    public class myInteger {

         private int data;

         public myInteger(int data) {
              this.data = data;
         }
    }
```

Now I have another class called `MainClass` which contains the main method. I am creating two objects: First object of the `java.lang.Integer` class and the second object of `myInteger` class. Then, I print both the object variables by passing the `integer` and `myInteger` to the `println` method.

```
    public class MainClass {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
               Integer integer = new Integer(1);
               myInteger myInteger = new myInteger(1);
               System.out.println(integer);
               System.out.println(myInteger);
           }
    }
```

I get the following output:

> 1
>
> MainClass.myInteger@67ea6afc

In the case of `Integer` class, I get the auto-unboxed integer value. But in the second case, I get reference.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to print `data` field of myInteger object without using any sort of `getter` methods?

Comment: Yes, by overriding `toString`.

Comment: My question is different from what's asked in the other question: Why does lang object print its value and user defined class print reference?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please have a look at my edited question in the last paragraph.

Comment: Because `Integer` overrides `toString`, and `myInteger` does not.